# show google maps in ASP.net modal pop up extender

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, modalpopupextender

I'm trying to show google maps in an ASP.net `ModalPopUpExtender`, but actually nothing is displayed.

It seems that I need to fire the JavaScript again, or just fire it off in the button click event that shows the modal popup.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the Google Maps javascript API call the google maps event after the modal popup is shown using the **add_shown** client side event of the modal popup extender.

here is the link on SO for the code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5500/168371