# Run javascript when modalpopupextender is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, modalpopupextender

This questions was already answered here - [How to specify javascript to run when ModalPopupExtender is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482/how-to-specify-javascript-to-run-when-modalpopupextender-is-shown) - but the accepted solution is not working for me.

The modalpopupextender is declared as below:

```
<ajaxtoolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" TargetControlID="btn"
        PopupControlID="pnlModal" PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlModalDragHandle"   BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
    CancelControlID="btnModal" DropShadow="true"/>
```

The showing / hiding works fine. What does not work is linking a client script to the showing event of the modal popup extender. Based on the original question, I tried:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
    var popup = $find('mpe');
    popup.add_shown(SetShowing);
    }

function SetShowing() {
    alert('showing');
  }

 </script>
```

Nothing happened. No alert, no errors. Reading further in the original post, I even added this line in the script: 
    Sys.Application.add_load(pageLoad);

The additional line had no effect. Any ideas why the original answer is not working? Thanks, I have been trying for hours.

Comment: try var popup=$find('<%=mpe.ClientID%>');

Comment: unfortunately that did not make it work. I tried adding an alert to the pageLoad() function and it never alerts, so I'm guessing pageLoad is never getting called.

Comment: try inside jquery document ready function $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: Sorry it wouldn't let me edit that one. I added:
            function $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('ready');
        });

No alert was shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to attack this problem another way. None of the suggestions were able to successfully detect when the modalpopupextender was displayed. I instead changed my approach to handle user actions on the shown elements - like focusing on a textbox, etc. I could be confident the modalpopupextender was displayed if the user was interacting with it.

If you came here, I would direct you to the original post here - [How to specify javascript to run when ModalPopupExtender is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482/how-to-specify-javascript-to-run-when-modalpopupextender-is-shown) - and hope you were more successful than I was.

Thank you to everyone who commented, I sincerely appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with "modalpopupextender",

but why not just use some jquery?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if ($('#mpe').is(':visible')){     
         //code for when MPE is visible here

     }

});
```

[jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

http://jsfiddle.net/N62g5/8/

Comment: That unfortunately did not work. When I added the code below, nothing occurred when the modelpopupextender was visible.
        $(document).ready(function(){
         if $('#mpe').is(':visible')){     
             //code for when MPE is visible here
             alert('It is showing');
         }

        });

Comment: sorry James, i missed a parentheses right after my "if"

Comment: I edited my original answer and linked a jsfiddle with working code, currently it just has two divs, one is not being displayed.. when the ID='mpe' being visible, the second div is displayed

Comment: Unfortunately, no joy. I tried add it to both the popupextender itself and outside of it, I tried adding a false alert and it did not fire at all. I guess the document.ready is never finding the document ready?
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#mpe').is(':visible')) {
            //code for when MPE is visible here
            alert('it is visible');
        } else {
            alert('it is not visible');
        }
    });

Comment: Im thinking that you have not imported `jquery` with whatever you are working with.. make sure you are dropping one of the versions in your html - right after your js script  see here [jquery-install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458349/installing-jquery)